# A strange Jensen's inequality for function of two variables

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I am reading a paper where they use implicitly the following "Jensen's inequality which i find quite strange. Moreover i did not find this result in any textbook so, i would like an opinion before i cite their result.
Here is the "Jensen's inequality" they use :

$f : \mathbb{R}^N \times \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ a measurable map. $X$,$Y$ two measurable maps $X,Y : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^N$ on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. $\mathcal{B}$ a sigma field (whose elements are in $\mathcal{F}$). Assuming for all $x$ $$y\to g(x,y)$$ is convex, is it true that $$E[f(X,Y) |\mathcal{B}] \geq f(X,E[Y|\mathcal{B}])$$ ? How can this be proved ? Do you have a counter example

Comment: The left hand side looks to me to be a scalar, and the right hand side a function over $\Omega$. Is the left hand side supposed to be only the expectation with respect to $Y$? If that's the case it looks like the standard application of Jensen's inequality to me.

Comment: How is the left side a scalar?

Comment: By the familiar Jensen, it is true that for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$, we have $E[f(x,Y)|\mathcal{B}] \geq f(x,E[Y|\mathcal{B}])$ (to prove this, just apply Jensen to $y \mapsto f(x,y)$). In particular this is true for all values $x=X(\omega)$, for $\omega \in \Omega$. I don't know if this can be useful, though.

Comment: This statement is true if in addition $X$ is $\mathcal{B}$--measureable.